# make phonethic keyboard in my android app only

Tags: java, android

HI I have tried to search so much but could not find out that

How to make phonetic keyboard, in Android like [Google Hindi Input](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.inputmethod.hindi&hl=en) is providing

Like I write in with English keyboard and Hindi Text will be written in EditText

[image]

I have seen one app is also doing same thing, in that there is two option online and offline,

I want to implement offline feature like this below app, they are implementing in their app only, I want to apply same thing like they have applied

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nichetech.hindi.editor&hl=en

there should be some thing character Mapping but I have no knowledge can anybody help me